# Worklight 6.2 Installation on WebSphere 8.5.5.1 Full Version

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8, worklight-server

Can we install Worklight 6.2 on WebSphere 8.5.5.1 Full Version (i.e not on Liberty Profile)? It would be great if someone has installation guide link for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.
Worklight supports WAS, WAS Liberty profile and Tomcat as the 'underlying' application server.

The procedure is the same.

- You install the application server
- You use the IBM Installation Manager to deploy the Worklight server artifacts, etc
- You use the Configurator tool to set-up the databases, deploy a project's .war, .adapter and .wlapp files
- This is all covered in the [Installing and configuring user documentation topic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/topics/c_install_config.html?lang=en)